# Which tense is better to talk about progress and development : present simple/ continues/ perfect?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-continuous, present-simple

> Prices are increasing.
>
> Prices have been/ have increased.
>
> Prices increase.

I know all of them are grammatically correct and all mean that prices increased in the past and still continue to increase in the future but I wonder what's the difference in meaning between the three of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Prices are increasing" means that currently prices are increasing over time, there is a gradual change happening.

"Prices increase" would mean that it is a characteristic of prices to increase, it is a general truth.

"Prices have been increasing" means that it has been happening for a period of the time, from the past until this moment.

"Prices have increased" means that the increasing has recently stopped, but the result is that things are more expensive now.